# Accessing ansible variables in filters

Tags: filter, ansible

I have been trying to create a filter, which prefix some input. The prefix should consist of some ansible variable in my case inventory_dir and role_name.

I tried to implement following code:

```
from ansible import errors

def role_file(self):
    try:
        return inventory_dir + "/roles/" + role_name
    except Exception, e:
        raise errors.AnsibleFilterError(
                'role_file plugin error: {0}, self={1},'.format(str(e), str(self)))

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' prefix a file resource to the inventory directory '''
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'role_file': role_file
        }
```

and my playbook looks as follows:

```
---
- hosts: messagebus
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "Hello World {{ 'abc' | role_file }}"
```

I get following error message:

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "role_file plugin error: global name 'inventory_dir' is not defined, self=abc,"}

Can anybody see what the issue is with the implementation

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you think `inventory_dir` should be available in Python code? What is the real reason for this filter?

Comment: I would have thought that any ansible variable would be available in the Python code as the code is executed in Python. But preferably in some sound API.

Regarding the second question. If you look at the section[best practices - alternative layout](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_best_practices.html#alternative-directory-layout). They are promoting a layout where each inventory is separated in each folder. At my current location this would most likely be the preferable way to structure the files, I would also like to place any files, which needs to be copied there as well.

Comment: You can define variable `inv_prefix: "{{ inventory_dir + '/roles/' + role_name }}"` and use it in `copy`/`template` as `src: "{{ inv_prefix }}/myfile"`.

Comment: It seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It seems to do the trick. Thanks a lot. Even if you make the expression global in group_vars/all

Answer (score 1):

Answer from the comments:

> You can define variable `inv_prefix: "{{ inventory_dir + '/roles/' + role_name }}"` and use it in `copy`/`template` as `src: "{{ inv_prefix }}/myfile"`

Comment: I would have to add +1 to your comment but unfortunately I need 15 or more in reputation. but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass along the variable to the python filter like:

```
{{ 'abc' | role_file(param2,param3) }}"

def role_file(self, param1,param2,param3):
    try:
        return param2 + "/roles/" + param3
```